# In gta v story mode more then half the guns say “out of stock” I’ve completed every mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In gta v story mode more then half the guns say “out of stock” I’ve completed every mission so I don’t know what to do
If any one knows anything help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Ammu-Nation never have any weapon in stock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277953/why-does-ammu-nation-never-have-any-weapon-in-stock)

Comment: The OP clearly states that he has completed every mission, unlike the poster and the accepted answer of the suggested duplicate.